# Weird Doctrine Entity Behaviour

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have two entities, Invoice and InvoiceItem definined as follows in yml.

Invoice.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Invoice:
type:   entity
table:  invoices
repositoryClass:   AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy:   AUTO
    ......

oneToMany:
  items:
    targetEntity: InvoiceItem
    mappedBy: invoice
  deductions:
    targetEntity: InvoiceDeduction
    mappedBy: invoice
  payments:
    targetEntity: InvoicePayment
    mappedBy: invoice
```

InvoiceItem.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\InvoiceItem:
type:   entity
table:  invoice_items
repositoryClass:   AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceItemRepository
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy:   AUTO
....
manyToOne:
  invoice:
    targetEntity: Invoice
    inversedBy: items
    joinColumn:
      invoice_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

My controller receives invoice details and saves the elements as illustrated below

```
public function createInvoiceAction(Request $request)
{
    ....
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->setReference($ref);
    $invoice->setInvoiceDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$request->query->get('invoiceDate')));
    $invoice->setDescription($request->query->get('summary'));
    $invoice->setAttn($request->query->get('att'));
    $invoice->setIsVatable($request->query->get('vattable') == 'true' ? 1 : 0);
    $invoice->setAdditionalInstructions($request->query->get('additional'));
    $invoice->setJob($job);
    $invoice->setCurrency($request->query->get('currency'));
    $invoice->setGeneratedBy($createdBy);
    $invoice->setFile($filename);
    $job->setStatus('Invoiced');
    $em->persist($invoice);
    $em->persist($job);
    $em->flush();

    $items = $request->query->get('items');
    for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++)
    {
      if($items[$i]['description']!= '' && $items[$i]['amount'] != '')
      {
        $item = new InvoiceItem();
        $item->setDescription($items[$i]['description']);
        $item->setAmount($items[$i]['amount']);
        $item->setInvoice($invoice);
        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
      }
    }

    $deductions = $request->query->get('deductions');
    for($i=0;$i<count($deductions);$i++)
    {
      if($deductions[$i]['description'] != '' && $deductions[$i]['value'] != '')
      {
        $deduction = new InvoiceDeduction();
        $deduction->setDescription($deductions[$i]['description']);
        $deduction->setValue($deductions[$i]['value']);
        $deduction->setIsPercentage($deductions[$i]['isPercentage'] == 'true' ? 1 : 0);
        $deduction->setInvoice($invoice);
        $em->persist($deduction);
        $em->flush();
      }
    }

    $html = $this->renderView('AppBundle:Default:invoice.html.twig', array('invoice' => $invoice));

    return new Response(
        $html
    );
}
```

invoice.html.twig which renders the invoice details including items and deductions.

```
.....

{% for item in invoice.items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.amount|number_format(0, '', ',') }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
.....
```

The challenge I'm having is that the $invoice object sent to the template is has no items or deductions which are supposed to be collections. I've checked in the database and can confirm that the items and deductions are persisted into the respective tables so I don't understand why there are no invoice.items or invoice.deductions in the tables.

Out of desperation I flushed after every InvoiceItem object creation thinking that maybe the template was rendered before the persist transaction was completed but this didn't help either.

Comment: Double check the invoice items database table.  I suspect that invoice_id is NULL?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Atleast one other error I've spotted is the onDelete option being defined under joinColumn. It should be:

```
manyToOne:
  invoice:
    targetEntity: Invoice
    inversedBy: items
    joinColumn:
      invoice_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
    onDelete: CASCADE
```

**--------**

If you are having this problem only when the view is rendered during createInvoiceAction, then the problem might be that since you don't actually add the InvoiceItem(s) to the Invoice object via a method called something like addItem() (the naming depends on how you name the relation in the invoice entity), those items might only be present in the Invoice entity the next time you query the invoice, because even though you have set the invoice of each item, it might be that if those entities were created just now, doctrine might not be able to retrieve them using the proxy classes. So the solution would be simple: use the addItem method on invoice entity to add the items to the invoice and then don't forget to add the logic that sets the invoice for the given item inside that method

```
public function addItem(InvoiceItem $item)
{
    $item->setInvoice($this);
    $this->items[] = $item;

    return $this;
}
```

However if this problem is still present the next time you query for the already persisted invoice and its items, I would suggest you check whether the object actually contains the getter methods and you aren't simply trying to access the items via a public property. In other words inside the invoice class the property named items should be defined as private, and you should have a getItems() method, which retrieves the items. 
Objects used with doctrine must have these methods, since it overrides the logic inside those methods using its proxy classes in order to add code that would also send out the query to retrieve the, in your case, InvoiceItem(s) from the database and place them inside of the private property of the object and only then run the getter code inside of your class. Without these methods private properties would stay empty, since there is no other way for doctrine to retrieve them form the database for you (unless maybe fetch: "EAGER").

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to review this. I'd already tried the first suggestion but it didn't work. 

This behaviour is really strange and only seems to be an issue at controller level, Using Sonata Admin, I am able to access invoice items using getter method but same won't work at the controller.

Comment: I have noticed an error with indentation of your InvoiceItem.yml file. You are defining cascade delete as one of the joinColumns. I've updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps :)